# How to add command line tools for math to Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, cmake

I am trying to solve [this issue](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-math/issues/198) on the gz-math repo. My initial approach was to make changes to CMakeFiles.txt inside gz-math and add a cpp code to convert a quaternion given in arguments to Euler Angles. However, this approach does not seem to work. The issue mentions the use of gz-tools or ign-tools and links a file as an example but I can't understand how to add a command line tool in that way. I would like the command usage to be like `gz math --quaternion_to_euler "0 0 0 1"`. How should I proceed? I have the equations for converting quaternions to Euler angles, but how can I integrate the tool in the way required? The command `gz` does not currently have an option called 'math', so that has to be created too. And in the end, which directory do these changes happen in? gz-math or gz-tools?

Answer (score 1):

The first step I'd take is to completely understand another gz command line tool.

https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-tools/

> Each subcommand is implemented in a plugin that belongs to a specific
> Gazebo project. For example, all the commands that start with gz topic
> ... are implemented by the Gazebo Transport library.

Trace out the code from `gz-tools` to an existing implementation and then find the plugin for that implementation and you should be in good shape to sketch one for `math`.

The Gazebo Transport command line tools seem to be implemented by the files in https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-transport/tree/gz-transport13/src/cmd, for example.